# Database context dependency injection is not working for a page's model

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc

I read somewhere in the ASP.NET Core documentation that I don't need to worry about how an instance of my database context will be passed to other controller and model classes as dependency injection will automatically do that for me. I declared a Database Context property in the Page's model class and then required an instance of the Database Context in the constructor of the model.

However, when I try to access the Database Context object from the Razor page associated with the model  then I get an error that my Database Context is not set to an instance of an object.

The controllers do not throw this error however despite implementing the same declare database context object as property and require it in the constructor.

Why is my database context null when I try to access it from the Model property of the Razor page and why is it not null when I access it from the controller?

```
// This property is accessed from the route
var id = Model.Id;

// Use the id to get all the information about this question
 var title = Model.dbctx.Posts.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == id).Title;

// The dbctx reference above is returning null
```

The code above is at the top of the Razor page.

Here is how the model for that Razor page looks like:

```
public class QuestionViewModel:PageModel
{
    // Get the id from the route
    [FromRoute]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    // The database context property
    public Dbctx dbctx { get; set; }

    // Require an object in the constructor
    public QuestionViewModel(Dbctx ctx)
    {
        dbctx = ctx;
    }
}
```

I use the same logic as the above in my controllers. The only difference is that I use private fields on my controllers and then pass the `Dbctx` reference to them via the constructors of the respective controllers.

How can I resolve this?

**Update:**

I do not know if it's the query that is returning null, but I redirect to this page after a new post object has been posted to the database. I then call databaseContext.SaveChanges() to make sure that the insert query was a success. I then grab the id of the last question that was inserted into database and then redirect to the QuestionView page as per the logic in this controller.

```
public IActionResult HandleNewPost(string Title, string Body, string Tags) {
    // Split the tags based on the space
    var tags = Tags.Split(' ');
    var tagList = new List<Tag>();
    tags.ToList().ForEach(tag => tagList.Add(new Tag(tag)));
    // Get the time the post was authored
    var creationTime = DateTime.Now;
    var postedBy = HttpContext.Session.GetString("email");
    var post = new Post {
        Title = Title,
        Body = Body,
        PostedBy = postedBy,
        Tags = tagList,
        Upvotes = 0,
        Downvotes = 0
    };
    // Post the object to database
    _dbctx.Posts.Add(post);
    _dbctx.SaveChanges();

    // Get the id of the last post and redirect to QuestionView page
    if(_dbctx.Posts.OrderBy(x=>x.Id).LastOrDefualt() != null) {
        var id = _dbctx.Posts.OrderBy(x => x.Id).LastOrDefault().Id;
        return RedirectToPage("/QuestionView", new []{id});
    }
    else {
        // Some custom code
    }
}
```

It is really weird that the error message starts with a different solution name. The name of my current solution is **InputHandling**, and there is another solution though in the repositories called ASPLearner. The QuestionView page is in the Page folder of my current solution, but the error stack begins with this line.

> ASPLearner.Pages.Pages_QuestionView.ExecuteAsync() in QuestionView.cshtml
> 7.var title = Model.dbctx.Posts.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == id).Title

Is Visual Studio confused and could this be the source of the error?

Comment: When using "property injection" you need to apply the `[Inject]` attribute to service-properties - that said, you should always prefer using constructor-parameters instead of mutable properties, because _only_ a constructor can make guarantees about class-invariants.

Comment: @Dai, Thanks for your comment. That being said I think the database context dbctx in my model needs that attribute,  Thank You.

Comment: @Dai,I added the property but the error persists let me edit add comprehensive details

Comment: Please show your `ConfigureServices` method.

Comment: @Dai, I updated.  The erorr begins with the name of another solution  instead of the name of the current solution, could this be the reason? Check the update post for more details.

Comment: @Dai, looks like the issue is with using FirstOrDefault instead of Where, why using the Where clause works while firstordefault returns null?

Comment: Why would you try and pass through the DatabaseContext instance through a model, rather than injecting it right into the page itself? I work a lot with Razor, and I've never seen anyone do it like this. I inject my instance like this: `[Inject] private ApplicationDbContext ApplicationDbContext { get; set; } = null!;`

Comment: @Bram, the issue is with the LINQ used to access the Database info. Some work while others don't.

Comment: The error stack doesn't seem to be complete, as it's only a part of the error. Are you sure it's not like a null reference error, as you are doing FirstOrDefault, and you instantly access the variable `Title`, while you haven't yet checked if the entity isn't null?

Try `var post = Model.dbctx.Posts.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == id);` and then check if post isn't null, and then get the title by doing `var title = post.Title;`

Comment: @Bram , I am sure that the title is not null because in the conttoller I just added a new record and called Save changes and grabbed the of the last record .I accessed the Title, Body and Tags successfully from the controller which means this is a Database Context being null issue

Comment: @Dai,The controller is not updating the Id of the last post property that was made to database. The [FromRoute] attribute in the Model always returns  0 when the database has more than ten records. But the id in the controller is working as expected, should I use TempData to pass the id to the model page ?

Comment: You should probably `Model.dbctx.Posts.Where(x => x.Id == id).Select(x => x.Title).FirstOrDefault()` so you don't return the whole `Post` instance if you only need one field. Plus that would avoid the whole null reference exception since you were assuming that `.FirstOrDefault` would always return a valid object. And I'm guessing you actually want `[BindProperty(SupportsGet = true)]` for your route property.

Comment: @JeremyLakeman, yes I was using caveman way of getting the last record posted to the posts table. You can query that record as long as the table is not empty which is a guarantee because I post a new value first before redirecting

Comment: HTTP is stateless. Always assume that the user will do something silly, like editing the url in the address bar. Never trust that the user will only do what you expect, in the order you expect them to do it.

Comment: @JeremyLakeman  what should I do to prevent them from wditing the url in the address bar? Should I encrypt using encrypt = multipart/form-data?

Comment: @JeremyLakeman, Aah I see. You mean they would edit the url to modify the id so they would access another record in database that they aren't supposed to see.

Answer (score 1):

This method may help you:

https://github.com/dotnet/EntityFramework.Docs/blob/main/entity-framework/core/dbcontext-configuration/index.md

Configure DBContext via AddDbContext

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddDbContext<BloggingContext>(options => options.UseSqlite("Data Source=blog.db"));
}
```

Add new constructor to your DBContext class

```
public class BloggingContext : DbContext
{
    public BloggingContext(DbContextOptions<BloggingContext> options)
      :base(options)
    { }

    public DbSet<Blog> Blogs { get; set; }
}
```

Inject context to your controllers

```
public class MyController
{
    private readonly BloggingContext _context;

    public MyController(BloggingContext context)
    {
      _context = context;
    }

    ...
}
```

Comment: I already have those definitions in the project, Thanks.

Comment: I cannot see the code that you are creating the instacne of your model in the page class? Could you please also post it?

Comment: I am able to access the Database Context from the controller but it is null when accessed from the razor page.

Comment: Mate, probably you are not passing reference between posts. In "HandleNewPost" method you need to pass your context to model.

If I cannot see full code (not the pieces you show), I cannot tell exact problem.

Comment: How do I pass the database context to the model from the controller action method?

Comment: Mate, you have a constructor with the context parameter. You can use it. QuestionViewModel(Dbctx ctx)

Comment: Let me check if the database context is null and then revert to you

Comment: The database context is not null, it's the id that's causing the issue.

Comment: The controller is not updating the Id of the last post property that was made to database. The [FromRoute] attribute in the Model always returns  0 when the database has more than ten records. But the id in the controller is working as expected, should I use TempData to pass the id to the model page ?

Comment: Yes you can use tempdata.